# Can using Vim-plug and Vundle together cause any issues in downloaded plugins?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-plug, plugin-vundle, plugin-managers

I am completely new to vim and have to download few plugins. I had initially downloaded some using Vundle and now want to get more using vim-plug. I fear this may cause (version?) issues if I happen to download same plugins from both plugin managers. Are there any known problems in using them simultaneously?

I know I could simply just switch to one and that is what I'll do if using them together causes any issues.

Answer (score 2):

*In theory* you could give the same path to both plugins managers so that they install the plugins in the same directory:

```
vim-plug
call plug#begin('/path/to/your/plugins')
vundle
call vundle#begin('/path/to/your/plugins')
```

*In theory* you could use one of the managers to install your plugins (`PlugInstall` for vim-plug or `PluginInstall` for Vundle), this plugin manager would then git clone the different git repository in `/path/to/your/plugin`.

To update the plugins *in theory* everything should be ok: you would use either `PluginUpdate` (Vundle) or `PlugUpdate` (vim-plug) to list these repository and use `git pull` in them, updating your plugins.

Where things might get fuzzy would be when Vim will source your vimrc: if you keep both `call plug#begin` and `call vundle#begin`, both plugins manager will try to load the plugins. It should work fine for the first one, the second one however could have some issues if the plugins don't have the right guards against being loaded several times.

*In practice* the real question is: Why would you want to do that? There is not pros to using two plugins managers: Is there is one plugin manager which is the only one to provide a feature you really need you should switch to this one completely. Keeping two in parallel will probably create more cons than pros.